# How to run multiple Javascript commands from a URL?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a bookmark that will navigate to page X, wait before it loads and then navigate to page Y. Page X is the one that logs me into something and leaves a login cookie.

In its simplest form, the following sample only navigates to X:

```
javascript:{document.location="X"; sleep(10); document.location="Y";}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: If it was possible - how would you protect from a script stealing your money from your bank account?

Comment: Can't be done in a bookmarklet. Javascript will only run in one window and when new window(page) loads it is gone.

Comment: Might be able to do what you need in a userscript for GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey

Comment: I don't think that will be up your alley but something like http://casperjs.org/ would be the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for answers, it's sad it won't work.

Comment: @zerkms: code doesn't intend to change cookie privacy, so I don't see how loading two pages in a row (as opposed to loading 1) can change risk of stealing data. Y can only read X cookies if they're in the same domain, or whatever policy is set by Y.

I also don't see why browser would restrict javascript copied in the address bar/bookmark. It's guaranteed trusted (or, if it was created by application ran locally, then security is already screwed, and this wouldn't create additional risk). Of course, my use case is just personal convenience for the apps I work with.

Comment: @morfizm if your solution worked as intended - you could do anything on the other page.

Comment: @zerkms: yes, but I still don't understand why it's an extra threat. Running javascript locally possesses all sorts of threats. Perhaps you're implying that security context of bookmarks is the same as "the current page"? If so, that would explain, but it's very counter-intuitive to me as of why to employ this restriction. Of course, javascript *on a page* should not be able to replace current window's location and then peek into results, but this is NOT javascript on a page, this is javascript in the address bar and in a bookmark.

Comment: @zerkms: OK, I thought about it a bit, and now it does make sense that address bar/bookmark javascript would run in the same security context as current page (because current page is what accessible by default, and then it would've been some sort of security violation if it had more powers than when a regular javascript on a page already has).